# When URLsession dataTask completed and how to do something after it done

Tags: ios, xcode

I get some data form api.

I need to it done then move to another page and set those data on label

I read more in many place, but still don't know how to do

I have a dataTask and I want to do something after it done

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response , error) in let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        if let data = data, let dataList = try? decoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: data) {
            self.state =  dataList.Success
            self.dept_code = dataList.Payload.dept_code
            self.dept_name = dataList.Payload.dept_name
            self.ename = dataList.Payload.ename
            self.name = dataList.Payload.name
            self.sys_order = dataList.Payload.sys_order
            self.sys_it = dataList.Payload.sys_it
            self.sys_card = dataList.Payload.sys_card
        } else {
            print("Error...")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    //want to do it after task done
    if self.state == true {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginS", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: is anything stopping you from putting the codes at the end of the chunk? either after `self.sys_card = dataList.Payload.sys_card` or after the entire if statement?

Comment: Don't put code in image

Comment: Please edit the question & add code instead of picture. So that people can search

Comment: once the task resume and will give you data in body itself which you will be getting after executive url only. Then what you want to do add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataTask` works asynchronously. Just put the code to perform the segue **into** the completion closure.

And **never** ignore a `Codable` error and print always the `error` instances rather than meaningless literal `"error"`.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response , error) in 

    guard let error = error else { print(error); return }
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let dataList = try decoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: data!) {
        self.state =  dataList.Success
        self.dept_code = dataList.Payload.dept_code
        self.dept_name = dataList.Payload.dept_name
        self.ename = dataList.Payload.ename
        self.name = dataList.Payload.name
        self.sys_order = dataList.Payload.sys_order
        self.sys_it = dataList.Payload.sys_it
        self.sys_card = dataList.Payload.sys_card
        if self.state == true {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginS", sender: self)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: You have to perform the segue on the main thread. I updated the answer.